# Iterate over all the fields and get their values in protobuf message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a dynamic `protobuf` message, and I don't know what fields this message contains.

What I want to do is, put all the values of all the fields into one string, for example, the message contains 2 fields, `string name = "Jack";` and `int age = 12;`, the final result I want is `"name:Jack, age:12"`.

Here is my idea, since I don't know what fields contained in this message, so I need to traverse the message to get all the fields' name, type (which can be accessed by `Descriptor`), and then get the value of each field, this is the most annoying part, because I need to write a long

```
switch (type) {
case TYPE_UINT32:
    //call get_uint32
    break;
case TYPE_UINT64:
    //call get_uint64
    break;
......
}
```

I wonder is there any other better idea to do this?

Comment: This looks like you want to export JSON, see: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.json_util

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what Protobuf's own `TextFormat` class does:

https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc#L1473

You can use that code as an example when writing your own. It is indeed rather tedious, but there's really no better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Message* message = &your_proto;
const google::protobuf::Descriptor* desc = message->GetDescriptor();
const google::protobuf::Reflection* ref = message->GetReflection();
for (int i = 0; i < desc->field_count(); ++i) {
  const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* field_desc = desc->field(i); 
  switch (field_desc->cpp_type()) {
    case google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_INT32:
      // call get_int32
      break;
    case google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_INT64:
      // call get_int64
      break;
    ...
  }
}
```